# Dropbox API overwrite upload files instead of rename it

Tags: dropbox-api

I am trying to upload some files to dropbox using their java API (version 2-beta-4), but some of these files have the same name.

What I would like to know is: What is the reason for I send a file (for instance "file.txt") to dropbox, this file is uploaded, but if I send another file with the same name (file.txt) dropbox overwrite the old file with this new one instead of renaming it to "file (1).txt", even I am setting autorename true and the WriteMode to add?

Code:

```
DbxRequestConfig config = new DbxRequestConfig("sample", "pt_BR");
String acessToken = "...";
client = new DbxClientV2(config, accessToken);

InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(file.getBytes());
FileMetadata file = client.files.uploadBuilder(path).mode(WriteMode.add).autorename(true)
                                                    .mute(true).run(input);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`WriteMode.add` is what's causing this behavior. "Add" means "Add a new file with this name," so it never overwrites an existing file. If you *want* to overwrite the existing file, use `WriteMode.overwrite`.

(Also, isn't it `WriteMode.add()` and `WriteMode.overwrite()`? I thought those were methods.)

Comment: overwrite is causing conflict too. What can we do?